# What is the correct way to update an element in elements list?

Tags: python

I created a list of elements and I want to update one of the list elements

This is the call to the update method:

```
companies_list = self.create_list("xpath", self.txt_company_name)
self.update_elem(companies_list[0], company1_name)
```

And this is the update method:

```
def update_elem(self, elem, text):
    elem.send_keys(text)
```

At the method I'm getting warning "Make function from method" and a suggestion "Method 'update_elem' may be 'static'"

What is the correct way to update the list element without getting warnings?

Comment: That method could indeed be static, or just a function, because it _doesn't use `self`_. Or just inline it, it's only one line anyway.

Comment: You don't use `self` in the method body so it's a function. Use `@staticmethod` and remove self to fix the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Pycharm, it thinks you wanted to declare the 'update_elem' as static as it does not change in the body of the method the class instance.

take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23555313/13658055), you basically need to add *@staticmethod* decorator or have 'update_elem' change the instance of the class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What further details do i need to add?

Comment: @Liorp either add `@staticmethod` decorator before `update_elem` method or have `update_elem` method change an attribute of the class - something like `self.elem.send_keys(text)` or `self.elem = elem.send_keys(text)`